# Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Shell

Tags: shell, vba, command-line-arguments, putty

I'd like to invoke a script on my linux server using VBA in Excel. To do this, I'm using a local copy of Putty that's in the path.

I've successfully written a single command to create a putty session and log in to the server, I'm just unsure how to pass another command after this has been opened in the shell.

Any Ideas?

The below subroutine works, but causes a problem when the second command is attempted.

Cheers

```
Sub test()
Dim putty As String
Dim strCommand As String
Dim strCommand1 As String
Dim User As String
Dim Pass As String
Dim Host As String
Dim File As String
Dim RemotePath As String

putty = """" & Range("E3").Text & "\Putty.exe"""
User = Range("E8").Text
Pass = Range("E9").Text
Host = Range("E7").Text
'File = """" & Range("E11").Text & """"
RemotePath = Range("E10").Text

strCommand = putty & " -l " & User & " -pw " & Pass & _
    " " & File & " " & Host & ":" & RemotePath
'MsgBox strCommand
Shell strCommand, 1 ' vbNormalFocus '
Module2.WaitFor (5)
Shell "ls -l > shell.log", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I realise that the last Shell execution won't work, as it's not a windows Shell command, but rather a Linux one.

I think my problem is how to get the shell that's invoked originally to take a another command. Even just the one command would do, so close!

Comment: separating the commands on one line, ie command a && command b didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

use other tool to execute shell command [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
execute this command by this code:

```
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal program_name As String, _
    ByVal window_style As VbAppWinStyle)
Dim process_id As Long
Dim process_handle As Long

    ' Start the program.
    On Error GoTo ShellError
    process_id = Shell(program_name, window_style)
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoEvents

    ' Wait for the program to finish.
    ' Get the process handle.
    process_handle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, process_id)
    If process_handle <> 0 Then
        WaitForSingleObject process_handle, INFINITE
        CloseHandle process_handle
    End If

    Exit Sub

ShellError:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, "Error"
End Sub

ShellAndWait "plink -pw password -noagent user@server.com ""rm -f /tmp/file.txt ; gunzip /tmp/file.txt.gz""", vbMaximizedFocus
```